# Managing user opt-in with Mailgun

Tags: email, mailgun

I have an app which sends a daily reminder message. If a user forgets to log in on certain days, it will send an email reminder. I want users to be able to unsubscribe to this reminder by clicking a link on the email. There may also be different kinds of subscription. For example, a user might not want daily emails, but they may want password reset, or blog emails.

Mailgun has an [unsubscribe feature](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-unsubscribes.html#unsubscribes). While this allows some control with tags, this seems to lack a resubscription option. They also have a mailing list, but that also seems more for blasting emails rather than opting in to notifications.

One option is to connect the email to my database. So that when the user clicks an unsubscribe link, it will flip a flag in my database such that the user isn't contacted regarding this email. But I can't find a way to do this, that doesn't involve giving the user an API link on the emails.

What are some options I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably would be able to accomplish this using Mailgun mailing lists (but I wouldn't for reasons below).  You'd have to maintain a list for each type of email that you want to send to users. So when you add/delete users from your system you'll have to use the API or control panel to add/remove from each of the lists. Mailgun can generate a unique unsubscribe url for each of the lists so that when the user hits unsubscribe from the email it will flag the email as unsubscribed for that one list.

From Mailgun docs:

> For managing unsubscribes in Mailing Lists, you can use
>   %mailing_list_unsubscribe_url%. We will generate the unique link to
>   unsubscribe from the mailing list. Once a recipient clicks on the
>   unsubscribe link, we mark the recipient as “unsubscribed” from this
>   list and they won’t get any further emails addressed to this list.

Mailing lists should work unless I don't understand your requirement.

From my point of view I'd just prefer to handle this inside my own system.  Otherwise you have to maintain your application's user records and then a separate mailgun list for each email type.  In multiple applications I have user email preferences stored in the db. The user (or customer admin login) can adjust preferences through the UI or in some cases by hitting unsubscribe link in an email which links to a web page (part of my app) "You have now unsubscribed to daily emails" -- the page sets the user as unsubscribed in my app DB.

Its extra work but the advantages to handling this in your app is:

1. You've only got one user DB (list) to maintain
2. List membership is easier to modify by the app user or app user account manager
3. It doesn't tie you as tightly to Mailgun -- in case you decide to
   choose another provider

More on Mailgun Mailing lists:
https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#mailing-lists